# PHP Form submitting on staging but breaking on live. How to debug?

Tags: php, forms

So I have a very simple form with just 2 fields that submits on the staging site, tested and got my clients to test and everything was fine.

Uploaded exactly the same code to the live site and it works for me but my clients just get the same empty form after submitting instead of the intended thank you message that should be showing in its place...there are no error messages and I can't seem to replicate this anywhere other than on the live site and i don't want to turn debugging mode on there.

I have also checked the host for error logs but unfortunately the host doesn't seem to have this feature.

How do I debug this or any information as to why it wouldn't be working would be super helpful.

I have gotten clients to hard refresh and clear browser cache. They have tried on multiple machines and in different places with the same result.

If you would like to take a look the staging site is here: http://ams.staging.gooi.ltd/

It's the Newsletter Sign Up button in the top left. This has been working for everyone that has tried though....like I said...only seems to not work on the live site for some people.

Comment: Check your PHP versions and extensions.
Enable error logging and var_dump to debug everything.

Comment: I think you need to show us the code you uploaded (everything related with the form)

Comment: The problem is that its specific to a CMS and a plugin for that CMS so I dont think many people would get it....perhaps I should ask on those forums